# How do I pivot datetime as values in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pivot-table, python-datetime

I would like to pivot datetime as values in pivot. The dataframe I have looks like below -

df

| Lane | Timestamp_arrival | Timestamp_departure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 12/17/2020 8:00:00 PM |  |
| a |  | 12/18/2020 12:00:00 AM |
| b | 12/18/2020 8:00:00 PM |  |
| b |  | 12/19/2020 12:00:00 AM |
| c | 12/20/2020 8:00:00 PM |  |
| c |  | 12/20/2020 12:00:00 AM |

The output required should be as below -

| Lane | Timestamp_arrival | Timestamp_departure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 12/17/2020 8:00:00 PM | 12/18/2020 12:00:00 AM |
| b | 12/18/2020 8:00:00 PM | 12/18/2020 12:00:00 AM |
| c | 12/20/2020 8:00:00 PM | 12/20/2020 12:00:00 AM |

I have tried the below but I am running into a **DataError: No numeric types to aggregate**

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'Lane', values = ['Timestamp_arrival', 'Timestamp_departure'])
```

This is a sample table. The actual table is much larger with a lot more time stamps for each lane(a,b,c). Their arrival and departures are in different rows and I want to get them in one row to perform mathematical operations on the timestamp.  Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
print(df.replace('', np.nan).groupby('Lane').apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: y.dropna().tolist()).iloc[0]).rename_axis('').reset_index().drop('', axis=1))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the code but it didnt work. It gave me all the lanes and removed all the time stamps.